# Dealing with Databinding Errors in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

This has been bugging me for a while but when I databind a control using with a Session variable as the parameter which has not been initialized there is an exception thrown which I can't seem to catch anywhere.

Ideally if the session varaible is not set I would just like to redirect but I can't seem to figure out where I need to check for this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the session object on page_init event.

Answer (score 0):

Check it in your page load.

```
Sub Page_Load()

if Not Page.ispostback()

if session("Value") <>"" then

me.hiddenfield.value = Session("ValueName")

Else

Response.redirect("PAge.aspx")

End if

End if

End Sub
```

I tend to add some hidden fields as sessions eventually time out

then make the datasource use the hidden control for its reference

Comment: page load event seems to be too late, interesting about using the hidden control though, i hadn't thought of that

Comment: It probably will be for the session, for the hidden field it will be ok